# Unrecognized chars in Eclipse IDE background

Tags: eclipse, ide

Today when I was opening my Eclipse IDE I was faced with these unrecognized chars in Eclipse IDE background, any ideas to how get rid from these chars?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've toggled on the showing of whitespace characters. Turn them off from the General->Editors->"Text Editors" Preference Page.